# Can not load driver class: org.postgresql.Driver

Tags: java, postgresql, maven, amazon-web-services

I have a java project that runs locally but not in server (`tomcat 8`)

I have this project in `Elastic Beanstalk` and `PostgreSQL` db in `RDS`, the project is not started after we change security groups, we get mistaken as

> Can not load driver class: org.postgresql.Driver

`PostgreSQL` jar file is in `/var/lib folder` (I got the same error before and it resolved after I loaded the PostgreSQL driver to the server, but it doesn't help me now)

Comment: Add the postgresql driver jar to your project WAR.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I did not notice that the war file's library had not postgresql driver. It was war file's problem, war files library was not the same as project's lib, did not understand why. I uploaded driver manually to the war file, and it worked!

But before the time it was enough just upload driver to server, and it's exactly the same project